# Qt creator can't locate Qwt plugin

Tags: qt, debian, qwt

I want to use the Qwt plugin in Qt Creator, but I have troubles installing it.

I work with Debian 10, Qwt 6.1.6, Qt Creator 4.8.2 and Qt 5.11.3.

I followed these instructions:

https://qwt.sourceforge.io/qwtinstall.html#qwtinstall-unix

These are the lines that I added to .bashrc:

```
QT_PLUGIN_PATH="/usr/local/qwt-6.1.6/plugins:$QT_PLUGIN_PATH" export QT_PLUGIN_PATH
```

I added this to my .pro file (this is a new project I started):

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/qwt-6.1.6/include
LIBS += -L/usr/local/qwt-6.1.6/lib -lqwt
CONFIG += qwt
```

However, I still don't see the new widgets in the UI form designer (after restarting Qt creator). I think Qt Creator hasn't located the Qwt plugin yet (although I am not sure).

I see some explanation about QWT_INSTALL_PLUGINS in the config.pri of the downloaded Qwt from sourceforge, but I am not sure how I should edit the .bashrc file.

Comment: Not really an answer, but do you have any specific reason to install QWT manually, instead of installing it with the package manager? That could save you from most of the issues.

Comment: I tried installing it with apt, but Qt Creator still doesn't show the Qwt widgets in the Design window. This is the link I used: https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/libqwt-qt5-6_6.1.3-1_amd64.deb.html